# how to configure IIS for a specific website nam

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Hi everyone,

> I have configured my web application using IIS7. It is running fine for http:// localhost/, but I need to give some website name like http://myexamsystem.com/
>   instead of "localhost".
>            I have tried all the possible ways from IIS7, but I am not getting the result.
>    Steps I did upto now:
>   Step 1: Right Click on "Sites".

Step 2: Selected "Add Website" option.

Step3:In "Add web site" dialog box:

Site Name:"myexamsystem", Application Pool: "DefaultAppPool"
Physical path: "desktop\myproject folder"
Binding

Type:HTTP, Ip address "All Unassigned", Port:80

Host Name: "myexamsystem.com"

OK

Error Messege:

This page can't be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://myexamsystem.com/ is correct.`

Comment: I hate to ask this, but... did you buy the domain? Set up the appropriate DNS records?

Comment: no, I did not buy..kindly help to this for local network..If I want to open my application from any other computer in the network, every time I need to provide the ip address..Kindly help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for debugging / local development, then you'll need to add an entry in your HOSTS files. This is located:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

It can be edited in notepad (if you have administrator rights on your machine). You just add the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1       myexamsystem.com
```

Note that this will only work locally. If you want it public, then you'll need to buy the domain name and point it to an external IP address.

## Update

Just seen your comment about it needing to run on your local network. A quick way is to add your internal network IP address to each machine's HOSTS files. You can find out your internal IP address by typing `ipconfig` into the command prompt. Then add it to the HOST file of the other machines in the same way as I descibed above, except use your internal IP in their HOST file rather than 127.0.0.1.

If you don't want to manually add them to each computer, then as far as I know, you'll need a DNS server.

Comment: 127.0.0.1       myexamsystem.com
I have done this, then I am able view my project only from my computer(hosted computer). I am unable to see from other computers on the same network, there are 300 computers on the network. It is not possible write in their host file.

Comment: Sorry, if your network is that big, then I can't really help. I've only had to do this for local development, not on a large corporate network. If your network is that big, then surely you have an IT department that can add this domain to a DNS server?